# When I click button for transition on CSS it makes a quick dash to the left

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-animations

I don't know why this is happening, I'm using Vue-router and when I click on the button to change the page, I want elements to fade out and fade in from above. I managed to do that but when I click the button the element shifts for about 30px left and then animations happens. I only have 2 pages, one where is only one element shifts more than the page where there are more elements. Any suggestions are welcome here is my code from APP Vue where transitions are happening and routes are loaded:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <transition name="fade" mode:out-in>
     <router-view></router-view>
   </transition>
 </div>
</template>


<style>
.fade-leave-active {
 transition: opacity 1s ease;
 opacity: 0;
 animation: fade-out 1s ease-out;
}

.fade-leave {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fade-enter-active {
 animation: fade-in 2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
 0% {
   opacity: 1;
 }
 60% {
   opacity: 0.4;
   transform: translateY(0px);
 }
 100% {
   opacity: 0;
   transform: translateY(-300px);
 }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
 0% {
   opacity: 0;
   transform: translateY(-300px);
 }
 60% {
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translateY(0);
 }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and there's a simple fix for this...

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <component :is="Component"></component>
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

omitting unnecessary keyframes

```css
.fade-enter-from {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(300px);
}
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-300px);
}
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.fade-enter-to,
.fade-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

You can use other two transition classes: `-enter` and `-leave` for more smooth animation. More references here: [transitions](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html), [router view's v-slot](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view-s-v-slot)